How to direct Biopython's Etools cache to a specified file instead of trying to generate at home/root?
I'm currently using etools as part of a nextflow pipeline on a cluster, but doing so attempts to put together a biopython directory before using the tools. I assume it tries to put it in the home directory, but that's not really possible given that this is not on my home computer and it's trying to place that outside of Nextflow's work space. So it's trying to generate that biopython cache in read only directories I don't own.
I've tried to see what they did to solve the problem in these two github issues: https://github.com/biopython/biopython/issues/1517, https://github.com/biopython/biopython/issues/918. But it wasn't clear to me how exactly the cache variable was exposed, and trying the following didn't solve the issue:
from Bio import Entrez
Entrez.cache = 'entrez_cache'
from Bio import Entrez

Here's the error message I've been receiving:
Command error:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/core/globus/cgi/raven/nf-core-raven/bin/focal_filter.py", line 10, in <module>
      from Bio.Entrez import Parser
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Bio/Entrez/Parser.py", line 351, in <module>
      class DataHandler(metaclass=DataHandlerMeta):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Bio/Entrez/Parser.py", line 320, in __init__
      cls.directory = None  # use default directory for local cache
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Bio/Entrez/Parser.py", line 342, in directory
      os.makedirs(cls.local_dtd_dir, exist_ok=True)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 213, in makedirs
      makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 213, in makedirs
      makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 213, in makedirs
      makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
    [Previous line repeated 3 more times]
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 223, in makedirs
      mkdir(name, mode)
  OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/home/FCAM'

